# Angular promises - Chaining reject and resolve channels separately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

## Situations

If I do this:

```
cookFood().then(function(food) {
    eatFood(food);
});
```

Whether cookFood rejects or resolves, eatFood will be executed. I don't want that, since I want it to execute only when it resolves, because that's what it was made for, not for handling errors.
Also if I do this:

```
cookFood().then(function(food) {
    return eatFood(food);
}, function() {
    console.error('Error coooking food');
    return 'FOOD_ERROR';
}).then(function(food) {
   return shitFood(food);
}, function(err) {
   if (err === 'FOOD_ERROR') {
       alert('Looks like there was an error cooking food...');
   }
});
```

I'll never get an alert, because I executed an error handler before. I don't want that, because I want to execute both. Also, "shitFood" will be called if there was an error, something undesirable.

## Solutions

I know solutions to both situations. I just think there "has to be a better way".

To the first one:

```
cookFood().then(function(food) {
    eatFood(food);
}, angular.noop);
```

Now eatFood won't be called with something that's not food. But do I have to use angular.noop every single time I don't want to handle the error (because I will do so later in the chain)?

To the second one:

```
cookFood().then(function(food) {
    return eatFood(food);
}, function() {
    console.error('Error coooking food');
    return $q.reject('FOOD_ERROR');
}).then(function(food) {
   return shitFood(food);
}, function(err) {
   if (err === 'FOOD_ERROR') {
       alert('Looks like there was an error cooking food...');
   }
});
```

This works as I expect, but I think I shouldn't need to manually reject, because the value handler does not have to manually resolve.

Mostly I'd like to clear any misconceptions I may have, and to be informed of a better way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: pretty sure if `cookFood()` rejects, `eatFood()` will not be called.

Comment: just double checked, `angular-promises` are Promises/A+ compliant so your original "situation" should work fine. I think you should double check `cookFood()` to make sure that it is actually resolving.

Comment: @thedarklord47 Yes, the previous promise was not actually rejecting, hence my confusion. Also, understood the wrong way an explanation from https://github.com/kriskowal/q (mentioned in my comment to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I do `cookFood().then(eatFood);`, whether cookFood rejects or resolves, eatFood will be executed.

No, that's untrue. `eatFood` will *only* be executed when `cookFood` fulfills. You don't have to pass `noop` or `null` or something as the rejection handler to get that behaviour.

> ```
> cookFood().then(function(food) {
>     return eatFood(food);
> }, function() {
>     console.error('Error coooking food');
>     return $q.reject('FOOD_ERROR');
> }).then(…);
> ```
>
> This works as I expect, but I think I shouldn't need to manually
>   reject, because the value handler does not have to manually resolve.

Yes, you always need to manually `return` a value if you want to signal a result. Whether that is a plain value, a promise that will fulfill or a promise that is rejected depends on the desired behaviour.

But you don't have to return a rejected promise, you can also just throw an exception:

```
cookFood().then(eatFood, function() {
    console.error('Error coooking food');
    throw new Error('FOOD_ERROR');
}).then(…);
```

Comment: "If I do cookFood().then(eatFood);, whether cookFood rejects or resolves, eatFood will be executed."

Looks like I was experiencing this because of not returning a rejected promise in the previous step in the chain, and erroneously thought it was because of what this phrase is referring to:

"If the getInputPromise() promise gets rejected and you omit the rejection handler, the error will go to outputPromise:"

(from https://github.com/kriskowal/q )

Got it. Accepting :)